# Tooltip like hints when cursor is on bracket in vs2010.

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ide

I'm looking to find the add-on which will draw a tooltip window at the top or bottom of the text editor whenever the cursor is next to a bracket.

The tooltip showed the lines of code surrounding the other bracket.

It was helpful to see method names whenever the methods where to big to fit on one screen.

I've done a clean install of vs2010, i think it was ether resharper or the productivity power tools. Although i can't find the option in ether of the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) will do that for you.